# How to change "Your name" label in comments form?

Tags: 7, forms, comments

I have a blog with comments and I need to change the "Your name" field to something different and make it a required field.

Can I do this from [`hook_form_comment_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) hook in `template.php` or in a comments template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in a `hook_form_alter()` function like you suggest:

```
function MYMODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $label = t('New label');
  if (isset($form['author']['_author'])) {
    $form['author']['_author']['#title'] = $label;
  }
  else {
    $form['author']['name']['#title'] = $label;
  }
}
```